# Error: "ValueError: cannot use sparse input in 'SVR' trained on dense data"?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, countvectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vector = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train).toarray()
print(vector.shape)
print(type(vector))
print(vector)    
vector
```

This gives class 'numpy.ndarray' with shape (97, 370)

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
clf = SVR(gamma='auto',cache_size=12000,max_iter=-1)
print("Training the data set...")
clf = clf.fit(vector, y_train)
print("Training Completed")
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
test_vectors
```

This gives <108x370 sparse matrix of type ''
    with 1212 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

```
clf.predict(test_vectors)
```

This gives the error "ValueError: cannot use sparse input in 'SVR' trained on dense data"

What is the problem here? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `.toarray()` as you have done for train data:

`test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(X_test).toarray()`